# Regular Expressions from array

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetAllServices1()
End Sub

Private Sub GetAllServices1()
    Dim services As ServiceProcess.ServiceController() = ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices
    Array.ForEach(services, Sub(s) ListBox1.Items.Add(s.DisplayName))
End Sub
```

Which works fine to list all services on the local machine.

Now what i would like to do is use reqular expressions to list only what i am looking for.  Depending on the version of the software the service names can differ

So something like this

```
Private Sub GetAllServices1()
    Dim services As ServiceProcess.ServiceController() = ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices
    Dim pattern As String = "(vmu\.? |wua\.? |W3S\.? )"
    If (service name matches pattern) then
        Array.ForEach(services, Sub(s) ListBox1.Items.Add(s.DisplayName))
    End if
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Regex.IsMatch` method to test each item in the array, like this:

```
Dim r As New Regex("(vmu\.? |wua\.? |W3S\.? )")
For Each i As ServiceProcess.ServiceController In services
    If r.IsMatch(i.DisplayName) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i.DisplayName)
    End If
Next
```

Or, if you prefer to use `Array.ForEach`, you just need to use a multi-line lambda expression, like this:

```
Dim r As New Regex("(vmu\.? |wua\.? |W3S\.? )")
Array.ForEach(services, Sub(s)
                            If r.IsMatch(s.DisplayName) Then
                                ListBox1.Items.Add(s.DisplayName)
                            End If
                        End Sub)
```

Comment: Forgive me i believe i have to concept of what you are trying to do however with both code example, when i fix the errors which i believe is because of misplaces parentheses it give me an empty box.

Comment: Then your RegEx pattern is probably wrong.  Are you sure there are supposed to be spaces after each of the question marks?  Is that really the beginning of the name of each matching service, or do you  merely intend to see if the name *contains* any of those strings?

Comment: I pulled the regex pattern from a different website. Im not sure which one, sorry. Yes that is the beginning of each name of the services. I would like to see if they do exist. I also have a function that gets all programs installed and would like to be able to accomplish the same thing. Instead of looking for "Coldfusion 9" i would like to look for "Cold" and list the rest. Hopefully that explains what im trying to do.

Comment: I feel like the first function i posted puts it in an array, and i can search for the service names using if statements, and get the proper output however i would like to be able to search common names instead.

Comment: You were right! I figured it out and thank you for all your help.<br>Working code<br>Dim r As New Regex("(\bAdobe\S*)") will find all services that start with Adobe. Exactly what i wanted.